# Angular does not re-render the component

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have a form that should display 2 fields if the checkbox "Sales" is ticked.
When the user clicks it manually, all goes well.

But I also have a button that checks this checkbox. When this happens, the 2 fields do not appear unless user manually re-clicks the checkbox.

You can see a screen capture here:
https://gfycat.com/WellmadeCapitalAdouri

child.html

```
<div *ngIf="userTemplates != null && roles != null && departments != null">
  <fieldset class="blue">
    <legend>Profiles SugarCRM</legend>
    <button (click)="handleClick($event, 'conseiller')">Ventes - Conseiller</button>
    <button (click)="handleClick($event, 'jm')">Ventes – Junior Manager</button>
    <button (click)="handleClick($event, 'manager')">Ventes - Manager</button>
    <button (click)="handleClick($event, 'assistant')">Ventes – Assistant de ventes</button>
    <button (click)="handleClick($event, 'qualite')">Agent Qualité</button>
    <button (click)="handleClick($event, 'compta')">Compta</button>
    <button (click)="handleClick($event, 'inactif')">Inactif</button>


    <div class="select subtitle">Hérite les préférence de l'utilisateur
      <select name="userToCopyHPfrom" [(ngModel)]="userValue">
        <option *ngFor="let user of userTemplates ; trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="user.value">
          {{ user.label | uppercase }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-list subtitle" id="sugar_role" ngModelGroup="roles">ROLE:
      <span *ngFor="let role of roles; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="role.checked" [name]="role.id">{{ role.name }}
        </label>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-list subtitle" id="sugar_departement" ngModelGroup="departments">DEPARTMENT:
      <span *ngFor="let department of departments ; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <label>
          <input [id]="department.id" type="checkbox" [name]="department.id" [ngModel]="department.checked" (ngModelChange)="onDepartmentChecked(department, $event)">{{ department.name }}
        </label>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div [hidden]="hideLeads">
      <label>Leads min
        <input
        type="number"
        name="leadsMin"
        [(ngModel)]="currentUser.leadsMin">
      </label>
    </div>

    <div [hidden]="hideLeads">
      <label>Leads max
        <input
        type="number"
        name="leadsMax"
        [(ngModel)]="currentUser.leadsMax">
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "mv-profiles",
  templateUrl: "./profiles.component.html",
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: NgForm,
    },
  ],
})

export class ProfilesComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    //
  }

public handleClick(e, type) {
    const departments = this.departments;
    const others = this.others;
    const orgas = this.orgas;
    this.resetSugar();

    switch (type) {
      case "conseiller":
      {
        this.userValue = "user_default";
        this.checkRoles(["Sales"]);
        this.checkStuff(departments, ["Ventes"]);
        this.checkStuff(others, ["Global", "Ventes", "Devis Cotation", "ROLE - Reservation"]);
        break;
      }

      case "jm":
      {
        this.userValue = "user_default_jm";
        this.selectedFunction = "jm";

        this.checkRoles(["Sales"]);
        this.checkStuff(departments, ["Ventes"]);
        this.checkStuff(others,
                        [
                        "Global",
                        "Ventes",
                        "Devis Cotation",
                        "ROLE - BI Validation",
                        "ROLE - ViewRCM",
                        "ROLE - View RM",
                        "Ventes",
                        ],
                        );
        break;
      }
      case "manager":
      {
        this.selectedFunction = "mgr";

        this.checkRoles(["Team Manager"]);
        this.checkStuff(departments, ["Ventes"]);
        this.checkStuff(others, [
                        "Global",
                        "Devis Cotation",                        "Devis V3",
                        "ROLE - BI Validation",
                        "Ventes",
                        ],
                        );
        break;
      }
      case "assistant":
      {
        this.selectedFunction = "av";
        this.checkRoles(["Reservation"]);
        this.checkStuff(departments, ["Ventes"]);
        this.checkStuff(others, [
                        "Devis V3",
                        "Devis Cotation",
                        "Global",
                        "Reservation",
                        "ROLE - Reservation",
                        ]);
        break;
      }
      case "qualite":
      {
        this.selectedFunction = "aq";
        this.selectedOffice = "Bureau - Billetterie & Qualité";
        this.selectedManager = "Manager du service qualité (Aminata)";

        this.checkRoles(["Quality Control"]);
        this.checkStuff(departments, ["Service Qualité"]);
        this.checkStuff(others, ["BackOffice", "Global", "SAV"]);
        this.checkStuff(orgas, ["BackOffice"]);
        break;
      }
      case "compta":
      {
        this.selectedOffice = "1377";

        this.checkRoles(["Accountant"]);
        this.checkStuff(departments, ["Comptabilité"]);
        this.checkStuff(others, ["Global", "ROLE - Affaire Validation", "ROLE - Create Provider"]);
        this.checkStuff(orgas, ["Compta"]);
        break;
      }
      case "inactif":
      {
        this.checkRoles(["ReadOnly"]);
        this.inactiveStatus = true;
        this.inactiveEmployee = true;
        break;
      }

      default:
      // code...
      break;
    }
  }

  public onDepartmentChecked(department, e) {
    if (department.id === "departments-Ventes") {
      this.hideLeads = !e;
    }
  }

  public checkStuff(where, arr) {
    let prefix;
    switch (where) {
      case this.orgas:
      prefix = "orgas";
      break;
      case this.departments:
      prefix = "departments";
      break;
      case this.others:
      prefix = "others";
      break;

      default:
      console.error("Wrong input");
      break;
    }
    arr.forEach((element) => {
      const myOther = where.find((other) => other.id === `${prefix}-${element}`);
      if (!!myOther) { myOther.checked = true; }
    });
  }

  public eraseFields(fields) {
    fields.forEach((field) => field = "");
  }

  public unCheck(array) {
    array.forEach((x) => x.checked = false);
  }

  public trackByFn(index, item) {
    const self = this;

    return item.id; // or index
  }

  private unCheckArrays(arrays) {
    arrays.forEach((array) => this.unCheck(array));
  }

  private resetSugar() {
    this.inactiveStatus = false,
    this.inactiveEmployee = false,
    this.currentUser.leadsMin = 15;
    this.currentUser.leadsMax = 45;
    this.userValue = "user_default_xx";
    this.selectedManager = null,
    this.eraseFields([
                     this.codeSON,
                     this.codeTourplan,
                     this.codevad,
                     this.groupes,
                     this.inbound,
                     this.outbound,
                     this.phoneExtension,
                     this.phoneNumber,
                     this.selectedOffice,
                     this.selectedFunction,
                     this.selectedOrganisation,
                     this.title,
                     ]);
    this.unCheckArrays([
                       this.roles,
                       this.departments,
                       this.others,
                       this.teams,
                       this.destinations,
                       this.orgas,
                       ]);
  }

  private checkRoles(rolesToCheck) {
    rolesToCheck.forEach((roleToCheck) => {
      this.roles.find((role) => role.name === roleToCheck).checked = true;
    });
  }
```

I have tried adding

```
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

and running the function inside a zone

```
this.zone.run(() => {...});
```

but none of these solutions changed anything

Comment: 'But I also have a button that checks this checkbox' can you include this code as well.

Comment: I have just added more code - I hope it's not too verbose. As you might have already guessed, I'm junior :) @Senal

Comment: Do you call the same logic of `handleClick` when do press the button? `detechChanges` should rather not be needed as it is run in response to button click anyway.

Comment: You're not changing `hideLeads` on your `checkStuff`, so it can never show. You should somehow call `onDepartmentChecked` in `handleClick` function so that both clicking a checkbox and clicking a button do the same functionality. Move all the logic to `onDepartmentChecked` and just call that method for each checkbox a button is related to in `handleClick`.

Comment: can you create stackblitz for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

When user manually click the checkbox its calling onDepartmentChecked() method but when and in that method you are setting hideleads to true or false but when you check that chebox using another methord u not calling this methord. thats the issue.

```
 public onDepartmentChecked(department, e) {
    if (department.id === "departments-Ventes") {
      this.hideLeads = !e;
    }
  }
```